# Testing RxJava .delay(20, SECONDS)

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rx-java, rx-java2

I need to test something like this

```
Observable.just(1).delay(20, SECONDS)
```

For test I used trampoline scheduler

```
Observable.just(1).delay(20, SECONDS, schedulers.getComputation())
```

and for test it returns  `Schedulers.trampoline()`
but this test is done in 20 second

What test scheduler or best test pattern should I use to get test result immediately and all others test continue working.

Comment: See [this blog post](https://medium.com/@vanniktech/taking-control-of-the-time-when-testing-rxjava-code-91b2e5e88bdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like in the linked blog, assume you have a class like this:

```java
class DelayedRepository {

    private final Scheduler scheduler;

    DelayedRepository(Scheduler scheduler) {
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    Observable<Integer> delayedInt() {
        return Observable.just(1)
                .delay(20, SECONDS, scheduler);
    }
}
```

Note that the injection of the scheduler via the constructor of the class is important.

Your test could look like this:

```java
public class DelayedRepositoryTest {

    DelayedRepository delayedRepository;
    TestScheduler testScheduler;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
        delayedRepository = new DelayedRepository(testScheduler);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIntegerOneIsEmittedAt20Seconds() {
        //arrange
        TestObserver<Integer> o = delayedRepository.delayedInt()
                .test();

        //act
        testScheduler.advanceTimeTo(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //assert
        o.assertValue(1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testNothingIsEmittedAt19Seconds() {
        //arrange
        TestObserver<Integer> o = delayedRepository.delayedInt()
                .test();

        //act
        testScheduler.advanceTimeTo(19, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //assert
        o.assertEmpty();
    }
}
```